# Javascript modules: return a bare object, or name it

Tags: javascript, module

Using the Javascript module pattern, what are the advantages/dis-advantages of returning a bare object containing the interface, versus creating a named object containing the interface, then returning a reference?  Example code below.  I always put the interface into a named object, and the one advantage I see of this is I can do some debugging before I return it.

```
function bareObjectModule() {
    return {
        method1: function() {}
        //etc.
    }
}

function namedObjectModule() {
    var namedObjectModule = {
        method1: function() {}
    }

    //debug here?
    return namedObjectModule;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage of returning the interface directly is that it is short and does not include much boilerplate but having a named reference is much more powerful and allows for other patterns that you could not originally. The biggest advantage is that it is much **easier to have the functions reference each other if you have a reference to the module**

```
var M = {};
M.f1 = function(){ ... };

M.f2 = function(){  M.f1() }; //functions can reference each other without
                              // a fragile dynamic binding through `this`

M.f3 = some_combinator(M.f2); //since you are not limited to defining things as 
                              //property-value pairs you have much more flexibility..

return M;
```

Comment: Very good points, my approach to sharing functionality between methods in the module interface, is to create "private" function declarations at the bottom of the closure (yes, below the return, they get hoisted), which actually works whether I'm returning a bare object as an interface, or a named reference

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: I don't like having to rely on hoisting. I prefer to put things on the normal order so that everything will still work if for some reason I have to use a var instead.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the debugging advantage you mentioned, i see no difference whatsoever in the 2 approaches. Since namedObjectModule is function local it'll anyway be discarded once the function returns (i.e. the variable name in the stack).

One minor point might be that with a named object, there will be a stack entry for the local variable 'namedObjectModule' (will be popped out once the function returns), and there will be an entry in the function call stack (to the same object) for the return to work. With bare object, the former can be avoided. Not sure if this has any real performance impact, unless you have thousands of objects in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that with a referenced object you can use properties and call methods from other methods. You can't do that with a single object literal.

As an alternative to both approaches, you can call the enclosing function as a constructor (with `new`) and have it return `this` object to export the module.

```
var myModule = new function () {
    this.methodA = function () { /* ... */ }

    this.methodB = function () { /* ... */ }

    console.log(this) // debug
}
```

No need to type `return` explicitly (constructors return `this` by default) and define an object literal (and come up with a name) as a bonus.

Comment: `new function () { }` is a confusing construct. Most style guides recommend you avoid it in favor of alternatives

Comment: I don't find this pattern confusing if you add extra magic parenthesis to make it look more like the traditional module pattern `(new function(){})`. I don't like how it depends on "this", though - I think the benefits of an explicit name for the module outweight the costs.

Comment: @missingno, good point about the context. Module pattern is supposed to be a namespaced collection of loosely related generic utilities rather than an object interface.